How to render camera backgound image into a texture?
I can render the camera view into a texture but when the camera has a background image it doesn't show it.
Is there any solution to it?
example code: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html#rendering-the-3d-view-into-a-texture
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.presets import draw_texture_2d

WIDTH = 512
HEIGHT = 256

offscreen = gpu.types.GPUOffScreen(WIDTH, HEIGHT)


def draw():
    context = bpy.context
    scene = context.scene

    view_matrix = scene.camera.matrix_world.inverted()

    projection_matrix = scene.camera.calc_matrix_camera(
        context.evaluated_depsgraph_get(), x=WIDTH, y=HEIGHT)

    offscreen.draw_view3d(
        scene,
        context.view_layer,
        context.space_data,
        context.region,
        view_matrix,
        projection_matrix,)

    gpu.state.depth_mask_set(False)
    draw_texture_2d(offscreen.texture_color, (10, 10), WIDTH, HEIGHT)


bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')


I think it's because the camera background image is an underlay and not actually seen by the camera projection

Any workaround?

You should be able to access the background image pixels from the image datablock, maybe you can as a first pass draw the pixels to the gpu texture, and as a second pass draw the view 3D ?

How to do that?

Good question. Maybe you can also use the Image as Planes addon to create actual geometry then it will appear in the render view. Cheers
